# Elasticsearch filtered search for sub-object fields

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I do a filtered search in ElasticSearch on a sub-object field? For example, my document has an `id`, and a `data` field which is a JSON array of how the data was stored in my database:

`{_id: 000, merchant: "merchant_1", email: "hello@email.com"}`

My search query:

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": { "term": { "data.merchant": "merchant_1"} },
        "query": {
            "query_string": {"query": "hello"} }
        }
    }
}
```

doesn't return anything, yet doing a query with just the query_string `hello` returns the correct rows. Changing `"data.merchant"` => `"merchant"` doesn't change anything either.

Am I doing something wrong here?

**Update:** I ended up just using a boolean query, which worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": { "term": { "data.merchant": "merchant_1"} },
        "query": {
            "query_string": {
                "default_field": "_all",
                "query": "hello"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should work for your case.